# How can I set makefile variables (CC, CFLAGS etc) to terminal or cmd using powershell scripts?

Tags: powershell, makefile, scripting, environment-variables, cross-platform

I want to write platform independent Makefile's environment variable setup script which can set Makefile's environment variable like CC, CFLAGS, LDFLAGS, LD etc. This is my make file. I want to run it on Window or Linux as per the user need. So instead of setting CC, CFLAGS, LDFLAGS, LD every time, I want to write a script which can set the variable for user depending on which platform they are using.

```
LDFLAG=-L..\..\test\lib
LIBS=-ltestlibs
INCLUDES = ..\..\test\inc
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)
EXECUTABLE = targetImage.exe
.PHONY: clean

all:  myprog

myprog: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAG) $(LIBS) -o $(EXECUTABLE)

$(OBJS): $(SRCS) $(INCLUDES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCLUDES) -c $(SRCS)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS) $(EXECUTABLE)
```

I know the .sh script but it can be run on CYGWIN or MINGW.

```
    #!/bin/sh

echo "Finding the current OS type"
echo
osType="$(uname -s)"
#osType=$1
case "${osType}" in
                "CYGWIN")
                {
                        echo "Running on CYGWIN."
                        CURRENT_OS=CYGWIN
                        export CC=""
                } ;;
                Linux*)
                {
                        echo "Running on Linux."
                        CURRENT_OS=Linux
                        export CC="-g -Wall"
                } ;;
                "MINGW")
                {
                        echo "Running on MINGW."
                        CURRENT_OS=MINGW
                } ;;
                "Thor96")
                {
                        source /opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/environment-setup-aarch64-poky-linux
                        CURRENT_OS=THOR96
                };;
                *)
                {
                        echo "Unsupported OS:${osType}, exiting"
                        exit
                } ;;
esac
echo ${CURRENT_OS}
```

But it can run on linux only. So how can I achieve the same using powershell .ps1 scripts ? So same script can work on any platform.
I have drafted this .ps1 file for reference but need to update it as I am not sure it's correct or not. Please guide me with proper solution. I am not able to find the proper solution for this.

```
Function RunOn-Windows
{
Write-Host 'The Script is Running on a Windows Machine'
$Env:CC = "gcc"
}

Function RunOn-Linux
{
Write-Host 'The Script is Running on a Linux Machine'
$Env:CC = "gcc"
}

Function RunOn-Mac
{
Write-Host 'The Script is Running on a Mac'
}

Function RunOn-Other
{
Write-Host 'The Script is Running on a Other'
$Env:CC = "aarch64-poky-linux-gcc"
}

If ($IsWindows) 
    {RunOn-Windows}
elseif ($IsLinux) 
    {RunOn-Linux}
elseif ($IsMacOS) 
    {RunOn-Mac}
else
    {RunOn-Other}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Windows box to do tests but if yours has GNU make available there is a chance that you can do what you want from inside your Makefile:

```
# List supported OS (as returned by uname -s, case sensitive)
SUPPORTED_OS := CYGWIN Linux MINGW Darwin

# Get OS
OS             := $(shell uname -s)

# Check if OS is supported
ifneq ($(filter-out $(SUPPORTED_OS),$(OS)),)
$(error Unsupported OS: $(OS))
endif

# Define all OS-dependent make variables as OS_VARIABLE
# Linux:
Linux_CC       := gcc
Linux_CFLAGS   := -g -Wall
Linux_LDFLAGS  := ...
# CIGWIN:
CYGWIN_CC      := ...
CYGWIN_CFLAGS  := ...
CYGWIN_LDFLAGS := ...
...

# Assign make variables
CC      := $($(OS)_CC)
CFLAGS  := $($(OS)_CFLAGS)
LDFLAGS := $($(OS)_LDFLAGS)
```